# How many bit are needed to represent 32 digit decimal number?

Tags: binary

A large number, 32 digit decimal number is given.
How many bit are needed to represent in binary ?

Comment: Are you familiar with how logarithms relate to the number of digits of a number in a particular base?  This is a straightforward application of that fact.

Comment: sorry sir, I don't know. I am searching that relationship.

Comment: number of digits is one more than greatest integer of logarithm

Comment: If there  is any equation , please explain it.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231742/proof-how-many-digits-does-a-number-have-lfloor-log-10-n-rfloor-1)

Comment: Answer: 107 bits $$\left\lceil \log_2 99,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999 \right\rceil = 107$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many bits needed to store a number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160295/how-many-bits-needed-to-store-a-number)

Comment: @InterstellarProbe floor and add one instead of using ceiling.  Otherwise you'll run into errors when asking about powers of two.  $\lceil\log_2(4)\rceil = 2$ but $4$ is represented as $100_2$ in binary requiring three digits, not $2$.

Comment: The number of base-$b$ digits to represent $n$ is $1+\lfloor\log_b(n)\rfloor$.

Comment: @JMoravitz ah, good point!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$2\leq\log_2(4)<\log_2(7)<3\leq\log_2(8)<\log_2(15)<4$

Comment: Maybe too abstract for the OP, he seems clueless about logarithms

Comment: you could have said $2=\log_24$ and $3=\log_2(8)$